# Must the Block in MKL sparse BSR format be Square?

Tags: sparse-matrix, intel-mkl

I am new to the MKL sparse blas, and want to use **BSR** as my sparse matrix format.

I notice that the block_size is specified by an **integer**. Does this mean the block must be a square matrix?

Is there a way to specify a **non-square block** in BSR?

Best,

Zhihao

Comment: Have you done some research, before asking these questions?

Comment: I searched the official document of bsr: (https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-sparse-blas-bsr-matrix-storage-format) It does not mention whether the block size must be square or not. In addition, the example of mkl only gives an example, in which block size is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when using mkl_sparse_?_create_bsr, the blocks are considered square.

No, I do not think there is a way to consider non-square blocks with MKL.

Note that I coded my own C subroutines to create BSR (i.e., BCSR) sparse matrices with rectangular (i.e. including non-square) blocks, perform the corresponding matrix-vector and matrix-matrix products as well to transform matrices from CSR to BSR. Let me know if you want me to share this code with you.

While 10+ years old papers did show some speedup of using BSR over CSR for matrix-vector products, judging from recent experience, I would tell you that using BSR formats does yield any significant speedup anymore of matrix-vector products over using CSR. This may be due to both the evolution of compilers which now better optimize CSR matrix-vector products, and the evolution of CPUs whose current memory layouts maybe less prone to these previously observed differences between the matrix-vector product of CSR and BSR.

PS: If someone still does observe speedups of matrix-vector products by using BSR over CSR storing formats while using current machines with current compilers, I would be very curious to know more about your test case.